# Input to different attributes values from a random.sample list

Tags: random, attributes, maya, uniform

so this is what I'm trying to do, and I'm not sure how cause I'm new to python. I've searched for a few options and I'm not sure why this doesn't work.

So I have 6 different nodes, in maya, called aiSwitch. I need to generate random different numbers from 0 to 6 and input that value in the aiSiwtch*.index.

In short the result should be
aiSwitch1.index = (random number from 0 to 5)
aiSwitch2.index = (another random number from 0 to 5 different than the one before)
And so on unil aiSwitch6.index

I tried the following:

```
import maya.cmds as mc
import random

allswtich = mc.ls('aiSwitch*')
    for i in allswitch:
    print i
    S = range(0,6)
    print S
    shuffle = random.sample(S, len(S))
    print shuffle
    for w in shuffle:
        print w
        mc.setAttr(i + '.index', w)
```

This is the result I get from the prints:

```
aiSwitch1 <-- from print i
[0,1,2,3,4,5] <--- from print S
[2,3,5,4,0,1] <--- from print Shuffle (random.sample results)
2
3
5
4
0
1  <--- from print w, every separated item in the random.sample list.
```

Now, this happens for every aiSwitch, cause it's in a loop of course. And the random numbers are always a different list cause it happens every time the loop runs.

So where is the problem then?

```
aiSwitch1.index = 1
```

And all the other aiSwitch*.index always take only the last item in the list but the time I get to do the setAttr. It seems to be that w is retaining the last value of the for loop. I don't quite understand how to

1. Get a random value from 0 to 5
2. Input that value in aiSwitch1.index
3. Get another random value from 0 to 6 different to the one before
4. Input that value in aiSwitch2.index
5. Repeat until aiSwitch5.index.

I did get it to work with the following form:

```
 allSwitch = mc.ls('aiSwitch')
 for i in allSwitch:
     mc.setAttr(i + '.index', random.uniform(0,5))
```

This gave a random number from 0 to 5 to all aiSwitch*.index, but some of them repeat. I think this works cause the value is being generated every time the loop runs, hence setting the attribute with a random number. But the numbers repeat and I was trying to avoid that. I also tried a shuffle but failed to get any values from it.

My main mistake seems to be that I'm generating a list and sampling it, but I'm failing to assign every different item from that list to different aiSwitch*.index nodes. And I'm running out of ideas for this.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
Jonathan.

Comment: Clue: `random.shuffle` the list `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the clue. Do you mean to add that shuffle in the last structure of code? Thanks again!

Comment: Just shuffle the list once and for all before you do anything else, then just loop through the shuffled values, using them as needed.

Comment: That's the bit that doesn't seem to work. Loop through the values, cause no matter what I do before, sample, shuffle or just a range, I alwasy get to assign the last value from the list. Thanks a lot for the clues though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a somewhat Pythonic way: shuffle the list of indices, then iterate over it using `zip` (which is useful for iterating over structures in parallel, which is what you need to do here):

```
import random

index = list(range(6))
random.shuffle(index)

allSwitch = mc.ls('aiSwitch*')
for i,j in zip(allSwitch,index):
    mc.setAttr(i + '.index', j)
```

Comment: Indeed this works! Thanks a lot man. The only missing thing in the code is the * after the aiSwitch (just saying that in case someone else tries to modify this code for their own purposes). Seems like the zip function is what I needed. Really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonathan I was going off your code snippet at the bottom of the question, though I will edit it in now. You can always mark the answer as "accepted" if it answers the question adequately.

Comment: Done! Thanks again John!